# Swift - Using SVGs and proper scale UIImage / UIBarButton

Tags: swift, svg, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem, xcasset

I just updated all of my icon asset files from .pdf to .svg. Unfortunately, now I'm having strange scaling issues when using the svg images.

It appears that the only way they scale correctly is when used inside of a view that has autolayout. (ie stackviews)

Anyone have any ideas or tips on how to solve this?

[image: Right bar button works.]

This is 2 Right bar Buttons. The cone is an svg and the circle is a system icon.

[image]
[image]

This is a cell where the constraints are being ignored

[image]
XC Assets

Thank you